# Something has been wrong with my finder and Mac. How to fix?

Tags: finder, xcode

Finder is often unresponsive.

Also in many software, like xcode or any project. I used to be able to right click and select open in Finder. Now if I do that nothing happen.

Zip utility is much slower. Takes minutes to solve.

I think this happen since I used ccleaner or something.

How to fix?

Finder seems to be the one affected. I wonder if there is other apps with option to "open in Finder" like xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug in 10.8.2](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2012/10/04/aesendmessage-bug-in-mac-os-x-10-8-2/) where occasionally revealing files in Finder stops working and Archive Utilility stops responding whenever you try to extract an archive.

As a workaround, you can terminate `appleeventsd` from Activity Monitor or with `sudo killall -kill appleeventsd`. (Without -kill other processes stop responding.) The issue will probably return within a few days or hours though.

Comment: There is no appleeventsd in activity monitor

Comment: Did you select the all processes view?

Comment: Selected as the right answer :)